# Eclipse IAM and Maven resolving dependency not listed in pom.xml

Tags: eclipse, maven, pom.xml

I have two Java projects:  Child and Parent with Child depending on Parent.  Project layout for both projects is shown below:

[image]

.class path for Parent and Child projects respectively, is listed below:

**Parent:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry excluding="src/" kind="src" path=""/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

**Child:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" kind="src" path="/ParentProject"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

Child has a dependency on parent as indicated in the classpathentry above.

I used [Eclipse Integration for Apache Maven plugin (IAM)](http://maven.apache.org/eclipse-plugin.html) to convert these Java projects to Maven projects.  The corresponding pom.xml files are listed below:

**Parent:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.parentco</groupId>
  <artifactId>ParentProject</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</project>
```

**Child:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.childco</groupId>
  <artifactId>ChildProject</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</project>
```

As you can see, child pom.xml has no dependency to Parent artifact.

I ran Maven Build using "clean install" goals on both projects, starting with the Parent and I see artifacts being deployed to my local repository.  Great.... but wait....
... Child's pom does not list a dependency to Parent yet Child project builds successfully, as indicated in the output console.

```
[DEBUG]   (f) packaging = jar
[DEBUG]   (f) pomFile = C:\Users\nji\workspace\ChildProject\pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) updateReleaseInfo = false
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10 for C:\Users\nji\.m2\repository
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\nji\workspace\ChildProject\target\ChildProject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\Users\nji\.m2\repository\org\childco\ChildProject\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\ChildProject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\nji\workspace\ChildProject\pom.xml to C:\Users\nji\.m2\repository\org\childco\ChildProject\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\ChildProject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[DEBUG] Installing org.childco:ChildProject:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml to C:\Users\nji\.m2\repository\org\childco\ChildProject\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\maven-metadata-local.xml
[DEBUG] Installing org.childco:ChildProject/maven-metadata.xml to C:\Users\nji\.m2\repository\org\childco\ChildProject\maven-metadata-local.xml
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.809s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Jul 19 17:05:08 EDT 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/217M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So, how did Maven pull this off without an explicit entry in pom.xml, even after it removed the classpathentry to Parent in .classpath ?

This is the .classpaths after projects were mavenized:

**Parent:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/J2SE-1.5"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

**Child:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/J2SE-1.5"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

Does it just quietly look in my local repository as a last resort?
Also, if I open the code editor to edit a class in Child that depends on Parent, I get resolution errors, which will probably be fixed if I add this dependency into the child's pom.  Is this not what IAM should have done?

Answer (score 0):

Maven won't explicitly write a dependency onto the pom.xml for you. But once you have a dependency listed in either of the pom files (parent or child), then maven should be able to have all the dependencies in the classpath, whereby it is able to deploy all the dependencies.

Maven builds the classpath variable only once, wherein it will have all the dependencies listed. hence you need not specify it multiple times.

Comment: So when IAM converts an eclipse project to maven, it doesn't convert the eclipse dependencies to pom dependencies?

Comment: in addition to @greyfairer question where is this classpath info?  Referring to my example, Parent's pom does not have any dependencies.  That is expected.  Child's pom does not have any dependency but somehow Maven is able to build the jar without dependency info.  How?

Comment: Are you sure that the dependencies are in none of the pom files? Neither in any standard path of the code? What are the dependencies in your eclipse? Are those dependencies covered there?

Comment: @gkris, The only thing in both pom files is artifact info.  I have updated the original post with some more info.

Comment: @gkris, what about m2eclipse.  Does it change info from .classpath to pom dependency?

Comment: There is no build cycle defined in the pom.xml for any of the projects? This is surprising.